# iOS8 Local Notification Permission for App Upgrade

Tags: permissions, notifications, ios8

In iOS 8, even UILocalNotification requires registration and explicit user permission.  Suppose I don't upgrade my app to iOS8/XCode 6 in time for iOS 8 launch and my app uses UILocationNotification (i.e. compiled in XCode 5 with iOS 7 as target).  What would happen after user upgrades their phone to iOS8?  Will the app stop being able to post UILocalNotification?

Comment: also if anyone knows if its possible to schedule a uilocalnotification without and user permission required features like alertSound alertBidy alertAction etc. that would be helpful as well. i was thinking i could get the base functionality i need and then optionally add extra stuff if the user allows it.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is if they already had your app installed pre-ios 8 you have a green light to send local notifications (unless the user manually turned them off in settings app). However if they've never had your app installed and you go to send a local notification the user will be prompted to allow or not allow notifications with the typical uialert that used to be reserved for push notifications. I don't know if this is documented anywhere.

Another thing I found was that although the docs say you can still send push or local notifications to the device, and although there will be no UI presented to the user that the app will still recieve the push notification. After testing this I found that to be false at least in terms of local notifications, i have not tried push notifications.